# Compare the records in a drop down list using webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Hello Team I'm a beginner in webdriver/java.

There is a drop down list(size 58) , and need to download any new record and if the list isn't updated with any new record then it will not download.

If the current is Sep, and the latest month is oct. It has to compare the sep and oct in the drop down list and then proceeds to download. I'm trying to store that drop down to List, but unable to apply for loop or iterator to compare the values. Tried with index values but failed.

Code:

```
driver.get("http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report");
    //maximizing the window
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      Wait(20000);

     WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("id=ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue"));       
    Select list = new Select(select);
      //System.out.println("list" +list);
     list.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Idk if I understand your question. But if you want to get all options for select and store them in List, then you can get a count of options from select by count function and then create a loop where you get option with index. When you will push it to List, then you can compare it. Or you can simply create a List of options.
To get count via xpath, you can create xpath like this:

```
count(//select[id,'ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']/option)
```

Or List with option elements.. Your code:

```
List<WebElement> listOfOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue'‌​]/option"));

    for(WebElement element : listOfOptions) {
        System.out.println(element.getText());
        if (element.getText() == "Sep 2015") {
            System.out.println("new month");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi i tried to get the no. of items in the drop down, but how to create a loop for the no. of values or how to create the loop using index?

Comment: If you are using List<WebElement> you can call size method to get count of elements. So then you can compute index :) I will update answer

Comment: Here is iteration for this filled List. What you have to do with element?

Comment: What I didn't get your question about element?

Comment: Question was about that if the update with iteration is enough for you, or what do you want to do with elements from List... If I can help you anymore?

Comment: May I know what will element do here?

Comment: Actually scenario is this:

Comment: You asking help with storing values of Select in List, so there is it. For loop is for iterating. You can access to values by element.getText() method. Is it all what you need?

Comment: I need to download the report for the new month which gets updated, so if i take Sep as the previous month and compares Sep with new Month txt, if it is not matching then that will be new month and that should get downloaded.

Comment: If the txt is matching, then no need to download. This is the actually scenario.

Comment: So how to get the txt of the new month and compares it with previous month? And if any time , if oct nov and dec updates at a time. Then again I have to compare all those new months text with old month. Hope I made it clear now.

Comment: This is the site: http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report and choose a month from Reporting period drop down to download new months reports

Comment: No once the new month is updated, after comparing the txt it decides that there is a new month then it will proceed to View report, to download the report.

Comment: So when you know size of List, you can access to index and compare them. Where you have a information what is OLD MONTH?

Comment: Sorry. actually I'm a very beginner to java unable to code what you said? could you please code me the above scenario if you don't mind? please

Comment: element.gettext(); printed me the complete drop down list, next what to do?

Comment: Say we can take old month as Sep 2015 conventional wells

Comment: Sorry my fail! Call a method getValue() for element in for.

Comment: element. getvalue() ? getvalue is not recoginized after element, that is giving red line error

Comment: List<WebElement> listOfOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));
    for(WebElement element : listOfOptions){
       //check your element or do everything else
     //element.getText();
     
     System.out.println(element.getText());
    }

Comment: the above printed completed drop down list

Comment: I can make the driver to select a particular month but problem is that if more months are added, that should compare text with Sep month and if that is not equal it downloads the new  month

Comment: You have a bad xpath! Watch code in answer... you have to find elementS! not element :) so add option to xpath like this: `List<WebElement> listOfOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue'‌​]/option"));` and call method System.out.println(element.getAttribute("value"));

Comment: But this is returning 0, how to get the text or index of a new month to compare?

Comment: Printing the complete list of months isn't helping, I need to compare new Month txt with old month txt

Comment: It is returning value attribute of element. If you need a content, you have to call getText, but call it for ELEMENT OPTION, not SELECT :)

Comment: what is old month txt?

Comment: It is Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)

Comment: So just compare element.getText() and this string. But be carefull, I saw that they have a &nbspc in source code.

Comment: List<WebElement> listOfOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));
    
    
    for(WebElement element : listOfOptions){
      if(element.getText()== "Sep 2015"){
       
       System.out.println("new month");
      }
    
       System.out.println(element.getAttribute("value"));
      
    }

Comment: The above also returning value 0 :(

Comment: List<WebElement> listOfOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));
    
   
    //Select listOfOptions=new Select(driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"))
   // select.selectByVisibleText(option.getText());
    for(WebElement element : listOfOptions){
     
   String ele= element.getText();
   
   
   System.out.println(ele); 
      if(ele== "Sep 2015"){
       
       System.out.println("new month");
      }

Comment: The above is again executing complete list

Comment: One more time.... your xpath selecting SELECT element. But you need its OPTIONS elements....

Comment: Ok answer was editted with your correct code. Try it. Your problem was that you selectiong SELECT element. But you need to select ALL elements (options) in select element.

Comment: xpath is throwing error The given selector .//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue'‌​]/option is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue'‌​]/option because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: And edited xpath : .//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue'] , then it printed complete drop down list

Comment: This xpath `.//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']/option` returning 58 elements.... 58 options of select. I am trying it now in FF via Firepath on your link and really 58 nodes

Comment: I tried this and it printed only oct month:  List<WebElement> selectedOption = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']/option[3]"));
      for(WebElement element : selectedOption) 
      {
       
        System.out.println(element.getText());
          if (element.getText() == "Sep 2015") {
              System.out.println("new month");
              System.out.println(element.getText());
          }
      }

Comment: but it is not initiating if loop :( oct and sep isn't compared

Comment: because you filled your list only with ONE element, option with index=3, to List contain only this one. Remove [3] from your xpath and run it again. And your name of variable, selectedOption, is not correct. It should call optionsOfSelect or simply options. then you will have a list of ALL options in select and you can compare all of them.

Comment: sorry I didn't get this "selectedOption, is not correct. It should call optionsOfSelect or simply options" , please could you please be more clear?

Comment: this variable, List, contain more then one elements.... It contain all options. So call it only as selected option is wrong, because this List containes ALL options.

Comment: hi just signed in , will check this again

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly this is what you want to achieve.

Lets say your `HTML` looks like:

```
<select id='month'>
  <option value="jan">January</option>
  <option value="feb">February</option>
  <option value="mar">March</option>
  <option value="apr">April</option>
</select>
```

You can get the total number of elements in the list by using below commands.

```
WebElement dropDownList = driver.findElement(By.id("month"));
List<WebElement> dropDownElements = dropDownList.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
int sizeOfDropdown = dropDownElements.size();
```

Once you have the `size` with you, next time when your `HTML` changes, you will have different size with you and then you can use any of the below methods to just directly jump on that particular index of your dropdown.

```
Select ele = new Select(driver);
ele.selectByIndex(count);
```

I think this helps.

If you want to fetch the text from an element, you may want to use `JavaScriptExecutor`, below is the implementation:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('#month option').text;", "");
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. Size is fine. How to compare old month text with New month txt from the drop down using iteration

Comment: I've modified the answer, you can take a look, I've used `JavaScriptExecutor` to fetch the text value from the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you, but I have to do this in java

Comment: Its in java only, Selenium Webdriver API provides an interface `JavaScriptExecutor` which you need to import. You can use this interface to execute all kind of javascripts in your browser.

Comment: but my lead asked me do it simple :( could you please do it in java?

Comment: You can't fetch the text of a select dropdown option. Only way is to use of this Interface.